# How to aggregate kafka messages that has a specific field to a single message and send it to a new topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, aggregation, kafka-producer-api

I have a kafka topic that I can consume from it messages that look like this

```
{
  "identifier": "123",
   "A" : "aa",
   "B" : "bb",
   "C": "cc"
},
{
  "identifier": "214",
   "A" : "gg",
   "B" : "rr",
   "C": "hh"
},
{
  "identifier": "123",
   "A" : ""qq",
   "B" : "ee",
   "C": "ll"
}
```

and I'd like to aggregate the messages that has the same "identifier" into one message to look like this

```
{
  "identifer": "123",
  "messages": 
   {
    "A" : "aa",
    "B" : "bb",
    "C" : "cc"
   },
   { 
     "A" : ""qq",
     "B" : "ee",
     "C": "ll"
   }
}, 
{
  "identifer": "214",
  "messages": 
   {
   "A" : "gg",
   "B" : "rr",
   "C": "hh"
   }
}
```

and sent it to a new topic.

Can someone explain to me what steps I need to do here? I'm very new to kafka in general and I've read about Kstream and Ktable but don't quite understand how can I apply it here. Thanks.

Comment: Do these records have keys that match the identifier? Have you tried any of the examples given in the docs to understand how kstreams works? Refer `groupByKey` https://kafka.apache.org/27/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#id12

Comment: @OneCricketeer, thanks for your reply.  The messages from the input topic doesn't have keys .. but I want to set the identifier as the key in the output topic.. From the link you shared I'm not sure if I should use groupByKey or groupBy ,, also I still don't get what are key, value and type in those examples and how to reach the final format of the message .. It would be nice if there's an example on a real schema like mine..thank you.

Comment: You can start with a transform or map call that relocates your identifier over to the key as just a string (or int), then you can groupByKey. Otherwise, groupBy more-or-less does the same, but not as explicit. In any case, you're going to have keys to do aggregations